# What should we do about questions that are duplicates off site?

Tags: discussion

For example, this question:

[How do I right-align text?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73138/how-do-i-right-align-text)

It already has an answer on StackOverflow as in the comments but marking as duplicate per the close reasons is not an option. The duplicate must exist here. What should we do about these?

Answer (score 5):

If the question is on-topic here, you can flag the off-site question for migration. You can also answer the on-topic question here; if a migration eventually occurs, then we can resolve the duplication or merge the answers as needed.

If the question is off-topic here, flag it or vote for closure here.

Answer (score -3):

What's wrong with just using an answer to link to the offsite question?
That might be the problem with this particular Stackexchange site...

You're over-complicating and adulterating a very simple and welcoming set of rules.

Comment: Link only answers are usually discouraged here.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on most SE sites. They don't fit easily into the collaborative answering paradigm of the site, since they cannot be directly edited and commentary requires off-site context. They are also subject to link rot or invalidation.

Comment: Your negative marking against a reasonable suggestion absolutely sums up the problem with this board. This is an awful developers resource, but an average 'boys' club.

Comment: While just linking is rightly wrong, the suggestion could easily become a "copy that answer", which is perfectly fine. Downvoting this was another way of being anal without even trying to _understand_ what was being said.

Comment: No. I most certainly meant LINK, because copying an offsite answer, rather than just linking to it, is a heinous thing to do.

Comment: Indeed, copying an offsite answer wholesale is very much frowned upon.